# Не могу создать список юникод-символов

Tags: python, unicode

Нужно создать список строк типа: '\U0001F000'

```
smiles = []
for i in range(10):
    smiles.append(f'\U0001F{random.randint(600, 900)}')
```

python даёт ошибку

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Буду благодарен, если расскажите как это сделать!

Конкатенация и срезы не помогли!

Comment: О диапазоне предполагаемых символов кода, последние три значения символа должны быть представлены только в виде натуральных трехзначных чисел, или все же нужен диапазон от 0x1F600 до 0x1F900?

Comment: В виде натуральных трёхзначных

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сформировать юникодный символ именно таким образом через подстановку в `\U...` не получится (можно в два этапа, но проще через `chr`, см. ниже).

Можно использовать просто функцию `chr`, при передаче в нее кода символа будет формироваться соответствующий символ, т.е. `chr(0x1F000) == "\U0001F000"`:

```
import random

random_part = 0xabc  # Заменить на random_part = random.randint(0x600, 0x900)

char = chr(0x1F000 + random_part)
print(repr(char))
print(char)
```

Вывод:

```
'\U0001fabc'
```

Ну и если нужен диапазон от `\U0001F600` до `\U0001F900`, то диапазон случайных чисел нужно задать в шестнадцатеричном виде: `random.randint(0x600, 0x900)` (т.к. код `0001F600` - шестнадцатеричный, `600` в нем - не десятичное число "шестьсот", а шестнадцатеричное число `0x600`).

Comment: Метод работает, но вы создаёте число, и прибавляете к нему число. Мне было бы удобнее манипуляциями со строками сделать. Но всё равно спасибо!

Comment: @Pushkin можно конечно и через конкатенацию, но будут требоваться дополнительные операции - либо преобразование в число (как в ответе Daniil Loban), или через формирование и декодирование `repr` строки через `ast.literal_eval`. В любом случае - только лишний гемор от этого, проще напрямую с числами работать.

Comment: На основе вашего ответа, получил такой код.
random_part = random.randint(600, 900)
smiles.append(chr(int('0x1F' + str(random_part), 16)))
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Pushkin, то же самое, только лишний гемор. Не понятно, что вы так привязались к этой конкатенации.

Comment: Плюс у вас пропускается часть чисел из диапазона от 0x600 до 0x900. Как пример - там есть такое число как `0x60A`, которое дает символ `\U0001F60A`, который вполне входит в диапазон от `\U0001F600` до `\U0001F900`

Comment: Говорю же, мне так удобнее, хотел получать символы из диапазона 1F600-1F900, при использовании вашего решения будет диапазон 1F258-1F384, из-за генерации рандома в десятичной системе, а кода в шестнадцатеричной

Comment: "при использовании вашего решения будет диапазон 1F258-1F384," - вы видимо последний абзац моего ответа не прочитали?

Comment: randint возвращает десятичное число, придётся его к шестнадцатеричному приводить. Это не важно, мне почему-то проще работать со строками, чем с числами

Comment: @Pushkin randint возвращает просто целое число (технически, оно вообще двоичное). Шестнадцатеричным или десятичным оно становится только при выводе на экран (в принципе, при преобразовании в человекочитаемый вид). Как делать нужный правильный диапазон я написал в ответе.